# Souslin space and functional

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I have a question about Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a Souslin space.

Let $E$ be a locally convex topological real vector space which is a Souslin space, that is, the continuous image of separable complete metric space.

I want to show $\mathcal{B}(E)=\sigma(E')$. Here $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\sigma(E)$ is  the smallest $σ$-field that makes
every $f ∈ E'$ measurable.

Since each $f ∈ E'$ is Borel measurable, $\sigma(E') \subset\mathcal{B}(E)$ is automatic.

I can prove $\mathcal{B}(E) \subset \sigma(E') $ when $E$ is separable Banach space by Hahn-Banach theorem. If $E$ is a locally convex topological real vector space which is a Souslin space, we can deduce $E$ is separable. But $E$ is not always normed space, I can't come back above argument. Let me know how to prove $\mathcal{B}(E) \subset \sigma(E') $